# Why do I need bundle exec to require this rubygem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a Rails app with some non-Rails-dependent files under `lib/services'. One of these files uses the [Domainatrix gem](https://github.com/dtuite/domainatrix).

```
require "domainatrix"

class SuggestionParser
  # various suggestion parsing methods
end
```

I have an empty spec for this file under `spec/lib`.

```
require "services/suggestion_parser"

describe SuggestionParser do
end
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run that spec without `bundle exec` I hit an error:

```
$: rspec spec/lib/services/suggestion_parser_spec.rb 
-> /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- domainatrix (LoadError)
```

Every other spec and gem in my project will run without using `bundle exec`. Why do I need to prefix this one in order to get it to run?

For convenience, here's a [link to the Domainatrix gemspec](https://github.com/dtuite/domainatrix/blob/master/domainatrix.gemspec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that domainatrix is declared using the `:path` or `:git` options in the Gemfile, neither of which install the gem in a way that makes it accessible to rubygems.

This could be confirmed if you post the line for domainatrix from the Gemfile.

Comment: Yeah I'm pulling it from Github so that's probably the problem. I'm just not sure what to do about that since I need to use a specific fork and the original gem appears to be unmaintained.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on why the `:path` and `:git` options make a gem inaccessible to rubygems?  I'm curious if this is something that could be patched

Answer (score 0):

try running the following commands:

```
$ rvm get head && rvm reload
$ chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler
$ bundle install --without production --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
```

This won't solve the specific problem with your gem, but it will take away the necessity to type in `bundle exec` every time you run your tests if you're using rvm.